# Google App Script - Search column, identify string, email contents of row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a script which, when run, emails me the contents of a row which is contains the words "duplicate".  I am very much a beginner and have been trying to piece it together from others' queries/answers - please bear with me.  What I've currently got was tested on a 12 row sheet and emailed me a list of 11 numbers (there were only three duplicate labels on the test) - [spreadsheet example.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vlLd1JxWknpMAiQCET6NK3x1_iX-PFe_cyDXgMIO4iY/edit?usp=sharing)

The issues are:

- it's not correctly identifying the duplicate label
- I want the contents of the row to be included in the email, not the location of the row

Thank you for your time and patience

```
function EmailDuplicates (){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var firstrow = 2;
  var column;
  var findDuplicate = sheet.getSheetValues(1,1,-1,1) 
  var rows = [];

  var email = 'person@email.com';
  var subject = 'duplicate';
  var message = '';

  for (var i = firstrow; i<= sheet.getLastRow(); i++){
    column = 1;
    findDuplicate = "Duplicate"

    do{
      if (sheet.getRange(i, column).isBlank()) {
        rows.push(i);
        findDuplicate = ; //no idea what to put here
      }
      else column ++;
    }
    while (column <= sheet.getLastColumn()&& findDuplicate);
  }

  if (rows.length == 0) message +- 'There were no duplicates today.';
  else {
    message +='The following rows had duplicates: <ul>';
    for (var i = 0; i <rows.length; i++) message += '<li>' + rows[i] + '</li>';
    message += '</ul>';
  }


  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
}
```

Comment: This is one of the most common of questions in this forum with numerous examples do some research and you will find many examples.

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favour and use the `filter` method on the values. That way you quickly get the subset of all rows that fulfill your criteria ("Duplicate"). Then iterate over those filtered rows. Using `forEach` is in most cases the *smoother* (and more modern) way instead of a for loop:

```js
function EmailDuplicates() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();

  let fvs = values.filter(function (row) { return row[0] == "Duplicate"});

  fvs.forEach(function (row) {
    Logger.log(row);
    // now do something with the record
  });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll have a play.